# Discrete Convolution of two piecewise sequences having this specific form

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

Assume I have the following two sequences :
$$
x[n]=\begin{cases}
\alpha&\text{if $a\leq n\leq b$}\\ \\ \tag{1}
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
h[n]=\begin{cases}
\beta&\text{if $c\leq n\leq d$}\\ \\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I was wondering in this case if the convolution :
$$
(x*h)[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]h[n-k] \tag{2}
$$
has a specific form applicable for these two piecewise sequences.

I have seen on the internet something like :
$$
(x * h)[n]=\sum_{k=\max (a, n-d)}^{\min (b, n-c)} x[k] h[n-k] . \tag{3}
$$
However, I can not confirm if this is true. I hope someone can provide a proper proof and thank you very much.

Comment: This is really straightforward. $k$ just needs to be inside $[a,b]$ and $n-k$ needs to be in $[c,d]$, that's all.

Comment: I see, but why does the boundaries of the summation are given as $\max(a,n-d)$ and $\min(b,n-c)$? @MattL.

Comment: intersection of sets...

Comment: Because $k$ needs to satisfy two sets of inequalities, so you need to make sure it does by using $max()$ and $min()$.

Comment: Ah I see, one last question is there a closed form for the output of the convolution in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$? @MattL.

Comment: E.g., $k\ge 0$ and $k\ge a$ is equivalent to $k\ge\max(0,a)$.

Comment: yes you can convert the sum in Eq-3 to a closed form expression.

Comment: I would be thankful if you can show me how sir @Fat32

Comment: The closed-form solution is easier to see if you visualize the convolution ('graphic convolution') as shown in many textbooks.

Comment: ok let me do it..

Comment: I would also like to thank @MattL. for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your Eq-3

$$
(x * h)[n]=\sum_{k=\max (a, n-d)}^{\min (b, n-c)} x[k] h[n-k] . \tag{1}
$$

where $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ are as in Eq-1, then you will have

$$
\sum_{k=\max (a, n-d)}^{\min (b, n-c)} \alpha \beta = \alpha \beta (\min (b, n-c)- \max (a, n-d) + 1). \tag{2}
$$

Where you should evaluate the closed form expression Eq.2 for the non-zero range of output given by the range of $n$ :
$a+c \leq n \leq b+d $

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: have you verified it? :-))

Comment: Your answer has a beautiful closed form so now it makes sense :)